# How much ram does my pc has?

Tags: memory

I want to turn this old pc into a home server.

When I bought it (few USD) I was told it has 4 GB ram but I only see 3072MB

The **SPD says slot0 2048** and **slot1 2048** but **DIMM** says 2048 and 1024.

So does it has 3 GB of ram ? on livecd it shows 3 gb as well

**Update**

```
 description: Motherboard
       product: P5KPL-AM SE

*-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
      physical id: 0
      version: 0702

 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 23
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 3GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 800 MHz (1,2 ns)
         product: PartNum0
         vendor: Manufacturer0
         physical id: 0
         serial: SerNum0
         slot: DIMM A1
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 800 MHz (1,2 ns)
         product: PartNum1
         vendor: Manufacturer1
         physical id: 1
         serial: SerNum1
         slot: DIMM B1
         size: 1GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
```

Comment: Having 4GiB RAM and being able to use it are two different aspects. I suspect that you are running a 32 bit OS which has 4GiB adress space, used for memory and other things like PCI-e config space. (Hence David question about graphics).

Comment: I installed ubuntu 14.04 (server) 64bit on it and same terminal output.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the BIOS, OS, or hardware is not set to remap (or not capable of remapping/accessing) memory above 4GB, so mappings that must fit in low memory reduce the amount of usable memory.

Check your BIOS for a setting called "memory remapping" or something similar. For 32-bit operating systems, turn it off to preserve as much space in low memory as possible. This may get you up to 3.5GB. For 64-bit operating systems, turn it off to remap as much memory above 4GB as possible. This should get you very close to 4GB.

It's also possible you only have 3GB of physical RAM. It would be helpful to know what motherboard you have and the part numbers of model numbers of the memory sticks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I updated the question, the remapping is enabled. But why is there a difference between SPD and DIMM

Comment: Does it have a dedicated graphics card, or is it sharing some of that RAM with the GPU?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes I think so it says 9500gt with 1 GB